# how to use django object in session

Tags: django, session

I was wondering how i can check if a object is in session and depending on that, do something.

```
def login_character(request, character_name):
    request.session['character'] = Character.objects.get(name=character_name)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

some other function:
if request.session['character']:
    print request.session['character'].name
else:
    print "nothing to see here"
```

How i try it, i kepe getting back to a KeyError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session` uses the standard Python dictionary interface, so you want either:

```
if 'character' in request.session:
    print request.session['character'].name
else:
    print "nothing to see here"
```

Or, in some cases, `request.session.get('character')` if you just want to have a default value if the key is not present.